# Connect to mining pool

Tags: java, android, sockets, stratum

I am trying to etablish a connection to a monero mining pool. I know that the mining pools using the stratum protocol. But the only thing I receive is a connection timeout if I try to create a socket:

```
try{
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("pool.supportxmr.com");
    Log.d("miner","Attempting to connect to " + address.toString() + " on port " + port + ".");

    Socket  socket = new Socket(address, 3333);
    Log.d("miner", "Connection success");
}catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

SupportXmr is just an example. Its not working with any pool. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with port `80`. Make sure you wrote `INTERNET` permission to `AndroidManifest` and use `AsnycTask`.

```
private class AsyncExec extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        int port=80;
        try
        {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("pool.supportxmr.com");
            Log.d("miner","Attempting to connect to " + address.toString() + " on port " + port + ".");

            Socket socket = new Socket(address, 3333);
            Log.d("miner", "Connection success");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

- Also don't forget to call new `AsyncExec().execute()`.

Comment: Port 333 was blocked. Thank you :)